# How to round a decimal to the nearest 0.5 (0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rounding

I want to round a number to the nearest `0.5`. Not every factor of `0.5`, **just** the `0.5`s.

For example, `0.5, 1.5, 2.5, -1.5, -2.5`. **NOT** `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5`.

I'm confusing myself just explaining it, so here are some examples of expected outputs.

```
0.678 => 0.5
0.999 => 0.5
1.265 => 1.5
-2.74 => -2.5
-19.2 => -19.5
```

I have tried the following code with no luck,

```js
let x = 1.296;
let y = Math.round(x);
let z = y + Math.sign(y) * .5; // 1.5 (Correct!)
```

```js
let x = -2.6;
let y = Math.round(x);
let z = y + Math.sign(y) * .5; // -3.5 (WRONG, should be -2.5)
```

The code makes sense in my head, but dosen't work for negative numbers. What am I missing that would make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can round to integer by

```
let x = 1.296;
let y = Math.round(x);
```

Then, you can subtract 0.5 first, then round, then add 0.5

```
let x = 1.296;
let y = Math.round(x-0.5);
let z = y + 0.5;
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function getValue (a){
   var lowerNumber = Math.floor(a);
   console.log(lowerNumber +0.5);
}

getValue(0.678);
getValue(0.999);
getValue(1.265);
getValue(-2.74);
getValue(-19.2);
```

looks like you want lower full number + 0.5 ;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this logic:

- Get the decimal part from number.
- Check if value is positive or negative. Based on this initialise a factor

  - For positive keep it 1
  - For negative keep it -1
- Multiply `0.5` with factor and add it to decimal

```js
var data = [ 0.678, -0.678, 0.999, 1.265, -2.74, -19.2 ]

const output = data.map((num) => {
  const decimal = parseInt(num)
  const factor = num < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  return decimal + (0.5 * factor)
})

console.log(output)
```